# Can a message acknowledgement be spoofed in SocketIO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In SocketIO you're able to get acknowledgements by providing a callback function, e.g. as per SocketIO's documentation:

```
// server-side
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("update item", (arg1, arg2, callback) => {
    console.log(arg1); // 1
    console.log(arg2); // { name: "updated" }
    callback({
      status: "ok"
    });
  });
});

// client-side
socket.emit("update item", "1", { name: "updated" }, (response) => {
  console.log(response.status); // ok
});
```

In my code, I prompt a user for a response and assume that the callback triggered can only be by the user I prompted. Is this assumption correct and is it a secure way to implement request-response functionality in SocketIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a message acknowledgement be spoofed in SocketIO?

Not very easily and not at all if using https.

If your socket.io connection was initiated with https, then you can be sure that a response from that socket is indeed from that same endpoint (e.g. from your server).  If the client sends a message and is waiting for a response from the server and gets a response, then that response is indeed from the endpoint that you connected to.  No other computer can take over that socket or inject into it.

If your socket.io connection was initiated with http, then there could be man-in-middle attacks that could alter responses while in flight, though that is more difficult with socket.io because it runs over the webSocket transport which has some security measures built-in.

If you really need this to be secure then initiate the socket.io connection with https and you should be fine.